# Deciphering Database ER Diagram for questionnaire

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, database-schema

I am trying to decipher a database ER diagram that a teacher of mine helped me make. I am mainly trying to figure out how to build the tables needed and combine them correctly.

The ER diagram in question is for an online questionnaire where every question is based on the answer given for the preceding one, eventually leading to a solution/ending.

Every question can have multiple answers and the same question can have multiple different answers, depending on the preceding answers given.

The combination table shows which answers are associated with which question and what the next question should be, if a specific answer is given, eventually leading to a solution.

The ER diagram looks like this:

[image]

What I do not understand:

The solution / question table will hold both questions and solutions, which can have different entities, but I do not understand how this is done? And what is the D?

The **leads to** is a junction table, because it's many to many connection between **Answer** and **Question / Solution**, but why? Are they not connected in the **Combination** table? - Does that table not hold all the information needed to know which answers are connected to what question and which question will be up next if a specific answer is chosen?

I have a very hard time figuring out how to build this database so it will work as wanted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your diagram is not a proper ER diagram.  In particular, the ovals with "Specific solution entities here" and "Specific question entities here" don't appear to indicate attributes of `Solution` and `Question` respectively.  That means `Question`, `Solution` and `Question/Solution` don't have any attributes.  Also, the `Combination` entity has `Answer ID` and `Question/Solution ID` as attributes instead of relating to the relevant entities.

Let's quickly review the elements of an ER diagram.

- Rectangles indicate entities, ovals indicate attributes.
- An underlined oval label indicates an attribute is part of the primary key that identifies the entity.
- Diamonds indicate relationships.
- Relationships are identified by the key attributes of the entities they relate.
- Relationships can have attributes too.
- A circle containing `d` or `o` indicates a disjoint or overlapping subtype relation.

Based on your requirements, I came up with the following functional and multivalued dependencies:

- QuestionID -> QuestionText
- AnswerID -> AnswerText
- AnswerID -> QuestionID (Possible answers)
- DecisionID -> QuestionID
- DecisionID ->> AnswerID (Available answers)
- DecisionID, AnswerID -> NextDecisionID

Based on this I suggest the following ER diagram:

[image: Decision tree ER diagram]

Translated to a tabular model (I denormalized relations with the same determinant, which is why there's no table for PossibleAnswers and DecisionQuestion):

[image: Decision tree database diagram]

Using this, you can describe any number of paths of questions, with a set of available answers for each decision referring to the next. Solutions aren't explicitly modeled, rather an AvailableAnswer without a NextDecisionID indicates a solution.

Comment: This is insanely brilliant and I thank you wholeheartedly for the work and thought you have put into this. Thank you very much! I have 2 questions though, how do you differentiate available answers and possible answers exactly? And would this not mean that a question can only be used once? And if so, would there be a way to easily change this, so questions can be used more than once? I did not specify that it should be possible to use them more than once, I am just making sure.

Comment: All possible answers for a question are represented in the Answers table while the AvailableAnswers table hold the allowed answers at each decision point.  You can reuse questions as many times as you wish at different decision points.  You could even create circular paths of questions.

Comment: I am going through your solution again and I am still astounded. I do have one more question though; in your tabular representation of the database, you have QuestionID as a foreign key within the Answers table. Would this not restrict answers to be tied to a single question? And therefor normalize the table, should I want the same answer, in two different questions? I might easily have misunderstood something and I would be very appreciative if you would explain. Thanks you in advance.

Comment: Yes, as I designed it each answer belongs to a single question.  If you want the allow the same answer in response to multiple questions, you can either create two separate answers with the same text, or change PossibleAnswers to a many-to-many relationship, which means you would have another table between Questions and Answers instead of QuestionID in Answers.